# Read data from two tables and writing into csv

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have to read data from two table and write it into csv file.
The tables structure is as follows:

1. Pressure Table. it is having 96 rows
2. Daily weather information table. It is having weather information for various cities.

The Table structure is shown below.

```
   1)  pressure_table                              2) Daily Weather Information   
        Date    | TimeStamp   | Pressure           WForecastDate    | TimeStamp   | RegionId  | Temp  | WindSpeed   | Humidity
    -------------------------------------          ---------------------------------
     2016-08-16 | 1           | 1000               2016-08-16      | 1            | 100       |  23   | 123         |23
     2016-08-16 | 2           | 2000               2016-08-16      | 2            | 100       |  24   | 123         |24
     2016-08-16 | 3           | 3500               2016-08-16      | 3            | 100       |  24   | 123         |22
     2016-08-16 | 4           | 4000               2016-08-16      | 4            | 100       |  23   | 123         |21
     2016-08-16 | 5           | 5000               2016-08-16      | 5            | 100       |  25   | 123         |27
     2016-08-16 | 6           | 6000               2016-08-16      | 6            | 100       |  24   | 123         |26
     2016-08-16 | 7           | 7000               2016-08-16      | 7            | 100       |  22   | 123         |27
     2016-08-16 | 8           | 8000               2016-08-16      | 8            | 100       |  21   | 123         |26
     2016-08-16 | 9           | 1200               2016-08-16      | 9            | 100       |  20   | 123         |23
     2016-08-16 | 10          | 1289               2016-08-16      | 1            | 101       |  23   | 123         |22
     2016-08-16 | 11          | 2312               2016-08-16      | 2            | 101       |  22   | 123         |21
     2016-08-16 | 12          | 7878               2016-08-16      | 3            | 101      |  21   | 123         |27
     2016-08-16 | 13          | 7676               2016-08-16      | 4            | 101       |  22   | 123         |25
     2016-08-16 | 14          | 1256               2016-08-16      | 5            | 101       |  21   | 123         |23             
     2016-08-16 | 15          | 5676               2016-08-16      | 6            | 101       |  21   | 123         |24
     ............................                  .................................
     ............................                  .................................
     2016-08-16 | 96          | 6541
```

I have to create the csv in the following format:

"DATE","TimeStamp","Pressure","Temp.100","Temp.101",WindSpeed.100","WindSpeed101",Hum101,Hum102
"01/08/2016",1,234,23,12,12,34,21,22
"01/08/2016",2,233,23,12,12,34,21,22
"01/08/2016",3,121,23,12,12,34,21,22
"01/08/2016",4,124,23,12,12,34,21,22
"01/08/2016",5,123,23,12,12,34,21,22
"01/08/2016",6,126,23,12,12,34,21,22
"01/08/2016",7,893,23,12,12,34,21,22
.....................................
***Total 96 blocks***
.....................................
"01/08/2016",96,893,23,12,12,34,21,22

What i have to do is to fetch all the ***Date,TimeStamp and Pressure*** information from ***Pressure Table*** i.e; all the 96 timestamps and the ***temperature,humidity and Windspeed*** information for the region 100,101 and for the same date and timestamp from  ***Daily Weather Information ***  table in a single row.

Currently what i am doing is running the following sql query.

```
SELECT Date,TimeStamp,Pressure FROM load_data_demand where date='2016-08-16'order by Date,TimeStamp;
```

Iterating through the resultSet and appending ***Date,TimeStamp and Pressure*** to the file and then executing the following queries to get the region temperature,humidity, and windspeed information

```
SELECT temp,WindSpeed,humidity FROM daily_weather_information where regionId=100 and Wforecastdate='2016-08-16' and timeStamp=1;

SELECT temp,WindSpeed,humidity FROM daily_weather_information where regionId=101 and Wforecastdate='2016-08-16' and timeStamp=1;
```

And appending the fetched information to the file.

My code is generating the csv file as expected but it is running too many queries. Can anyone give me with a query for the above scenario which can produce the result set with less number of queries or single query.

Comment: what is the purpose of the file ?(since you have a database), you can merge the two tables or use one request but it will a bit heavy

Comment: This csv will be used as input to another system. So i has to be generated

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011220/read-data-from-two-tables-and-writing-into-csv
create table pressure_table(`Date` date    , TimeStamp int  , Pressure   int);        
truncate table pressure_table;
insert into pressure_table values        
     ('2016-08-16' , 1           , 1000),              
     ('2016-08-16' , 2           , 2000),              
     ('2016-08-16' , 3           , 3500),               
     ('2016-08-16' , 4           , 4000),               
     ('2016-08-16' , 5           , 5000),               
     ('2016-08-16' , 6           , 6000),              
     ('2016-08-16' , 7           , 7000),              
     ('2016-08-16' , 8           , 8000),              
     ('2016-08-16' , 9           , 1200),               
     ('2016-08-16' , 10          , 1289),              
     ('2016-08-16' , 11          , 2312),               
     ('2016-08-16' , 12          , 7878),               
     ('2016-08-16' , 13          , 7676),              
     ('2016-08-16' , 14          , 1256),                          
     ('2016-08-16' , 15          , 5676);   


create table Daily_Weather_Information(WForecastDate date   , TimeStamp   int, RegionId int , Temp  int, WindSpeed int  , Humidity int);
truncate table daily_weather_information;
insert into daily_weather_information    values 
     ('2016-08-16'      , 1            , 100       ,  23   , 123         ,23),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 2            , 100       ,  24   , 123         ,24),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 3            , 100       ,  24   , 123         ,22),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 4            , 100       ,  23   , 123         ,21),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 5            , 100       ,  25   , 123         ,27),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 6            , 100       ,  24   , 123         ,26),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 7            , 100       ,  22   , 123         ,27),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 8            , 100       ,  21   , 123         ,26),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 9            , 100       ,  20   , 123         ,23),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 1            , 101       ,  23   , 123         ,22),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 2            , 101       ,  22   , 123         ,21),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 3            , 101       ,  21   , 123         ,27),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 4            , 101       ,  22   , 123         ,25),
     ('2016-08-16'      , 5            , 101       ,  21   , 123         ,23),            
     ('2016-08-16'      , 6            , 101       ,  21   , 123         ,24);  
      */  

select p.`date`,p.timestamp,p.pressure,
        max(case when regionid = 100 then temp else 0 end) as temp100,
        max(case when regionid = 101 then temp else 0 end) as temp101,
        max(case when regionid = 100 then windspeed else 0 end) as windspeed100,
        max(case when regionid = 101 then windspeed else 0 end) as windspeed101,
        max(case when regionid = 100 then humidity else 0 end) as humidity100,
        max(case when regionid = 101 then humidity else 0 end) as humidity101
from    pressure_table p
join  daily_weather_information i on i.timestamp = p.timestamp
group by  p.`date`,p.timestamp,p.pressure
order   by  p.`date`,p.timestamp,p.pressure
```

Answer (score -3):

There are many possibilities. if you're attempting to join the two tables by the attribut "date".

So you can do it like this in a single query :

```
SELECT Date,TimeStamp,Pressure,temp,WindSpeed,humidity FROM 
load_data_demand l, daily_weather_information d
WHERE l.Date = d.WForecastDate 
AND d.timeStamp = 1
AND (d.RegionId = 100 OR d.RegionId=101)
order by l.Date, d.Timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this query is generating  result set with redundant "timeStamp" from "Load_data_demand". What i need is  data,timeStamp, with temperature, humidity and windcover for the different region is the single row. As shown in the csv format

Comment: So you can specify that it with the alias l and d.  Select d.Date,d.TimeStamp,.....

Comment: Date ,TimeStamp,Pressure,TempForRegion100,TempForRegion101,WindspeedForRegion100,WindspeedForRegion101,HumidityForRegion100,HumidityForRegion101  . I want to get in this format